# git id in rpm spec summary to populate from %prep

Tags: git, macros, rpm, specifications

in my rpm spec's %prep section I'm doing

if [ -d target ] ; then
   git pull;
else
   git clone;
fi

pushd target

%define         _gitVer      %(git rev-parse HEAD)

and want this in my rpm summary like

Summary:   My Target %{_gitVer}

The goal is to do

rpm -qpi

and decide if we need to build new rpm or not

Is there a way to do that? defining the macro in %prep is not picked up in summary

thanks

-tg-

Comment: Macros are evaluated where they appear, so this is normal -- a non defined value will return a null string. Also, you should be doing a clean build each time, building from existing source is not a very good idea.

Comment: its not, it does a git stash; git pull

Comment: Thanks, you are right, its better to tackle it from a build script.